# How to configure KnpPiwikBundle and Piwik to analytics of web application in Symfony2 using apache server

Tags: apache, symfony, matomo

I'm using piwik in my localhost apache server(xampp) and configured KnpPiwikBundle, i ve set virtualhost to run two host at same time i.e my web application and piwik.
My autoload i heve defined as following ..

```
define('PIWIK_INCLUDE_PATH', realpath('piwik/'));
define('PIWIK_USER_PATH', realpath('piwik/'));
define('PIWIK_ENABLE_DISPATCH', false);
define('PIWIK_ENABLE_ERROR_HANDLER', false);
define('PIWIK_ENABLE_SESSION_START', false);
require_once PIWIK_INCLUDE_PATH . "C:xampp/htdocs/piwik/index.php";
require_once PIWIK_INCLUDE_PATH . "C:/xampp/htdocs/piwik/core/API/Request.php";
Piwik_FrontController::getInstance()->init();
```

The following error i'm facing in webpage

```
"Warning: file_get_contents(/plugins/Zeitgeist/templates/simpleLayoutHeader.tpl):
failed to open stream: No such file or directory in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\piwik\core\testMinimumPhpVersion.php on line 111

Warning: file_get_contents(/plugins/Zeitgeist/templates/simpleLayoutFooter.tpl): 
failed to open stream: No such file or directory in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\piwik\core\testMinimumPhpVersion.php on line 112
```

It appears the composer tool is not yet installed. You can install Composer in a few easy steps:
Download and run Composer-Setup.exe, it will install the latest Composer version and set up your PATH so that you can just call composer from any directory in your command line.
Then run this command in a terminal in the piwik directory:
$ php composer.phar update This will initialize composer for Piwik and download libraries we use in vendor/* directory. "